# call external table for a query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a search for objects by coordinates passed by a table that I send to the database in which I'm searching for these objects. The script is as follows:

```
SELECT 
  win.ID as ID, p.x, p.y, p.cor, p.eq as coef, g.cor1

FROM Informations as p, mydb.windows as win
  
join dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq(win.x,  win.y, 40) n
on
p.value1 = n.value1
join  Additions as g
on
n.value1 = g.value1

WHERE                 
   p.z between win.z_min and win.z_maz
```

The `dbo.fgetnearbycoordeq` function is native to the SQL database used and gives all objects within a radius of 40 cm taking as their center the coordinates `win.x` and `win.y` that I passed through the table I uploaded and "called " through `mydb`. (which is how I reference tables sent to the database).

The error presented is

```
The multi-part identifier "win.x" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "win.y" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "p.value1" could not be bound.
```

Thanks in advance for the help and possible tips.

Comment: Are you sure `mysql` is the correct tag? The `dbo` schema implies `sql-server`, which is a different product completely. The answers to this question for MySql and completely different than the answers for Sql Server, so this is something you need to get right if you want to solve your problem.

Comment: Also, don't use the old `TableA, TableB` syntax for joins. It's been obsolete for 25 years now. **ESPECIALLY** don't mix the old obsolete syntax with the _correct_ (because at this point the old syntax really should be seen as _incorrect_) `TableA join TableB` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Given the use of `dbo`, I expect this question is really about Sql Server rather than MySql.

With that in mind, if you specify a database name as part of an object, Sql Server requires that you *must* then fully-qualify the entire name. This means including the schema as part of the name.

Therefore `mydb.windows`, where `mydb` is a database and `windows` is a table, should really be something like `mydb.dbo.windows` (assuming the `dbo` schema). You can shorthand this to use the default schema (usually `dbo`) like this: `mydb..windows`, but you can't omit the schema completely.

Finally, you already did this but it's worth mentioning that when you use full names like this, you *must* also give the object an **alias**. So `mydb.windows` actually becomes `mydb.dbo.windows as win`.